# Using composer-added dependencies in the php interactive shell

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to use my composer added dependencies in the php shell, but it does not work.

I am using this gist [ https://gist.github.com/gigorok/5ca39384635113495796 ]

```
php -a -d auto_prepend_file=./vendor/autoload.php
```

I attempt to run, the same :

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::parse('today');
```

After this line I get: PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Carbon' not found in php shell code:1

It is worth noting that I have a codecept tests running which use Carbon with the same use statement and they work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php), autoloading doesn't work in interactive shell:

> Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode

Answer (score -3):

This may help.

```
cd /your/application/dir
rm bootstrap/compiled.php
rm -rf vendor
composer install --no-dev
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful. Why do you think these steps could help or are necessary?

Comment: An explanation would be useful. Why do you think these steps could help or are necessary?